# Separate files for individual python loggers

Tags: python, logging, handler

I have created a logger called userlog:

```
self.ulog = logging.getLogger('userlog')
```

Then added a file handler

```
handler=logging.FileHandler(fileLoc,'w')
self.ulog.addHandler(handler)
```

But all logging calls to ulog also appear in the log specified by the defaultConfig of the python logging library, how do I have these lines not appear in the default log, and only in the file specified by the handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `self.ulog.propagate` property to `False`.
Look at the `Logger` documentation for more details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate